# Proving that every graph has an order such that Bellman Ford can run in one iteration

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I need to prove that for every given graph, that doesn't contain negative cycles, there is an order of edges so that Bellman-Ford algorithm will finish running after one iteration.

I could only solve it to graphs that are DAGs using topological sort, but couldn't find a way proving it for every graph.

Comment: Hint: the graph may not be a DAG, but the shortest path tree is a DAG.